# en mi android studio no se visualiza los componentes que voy agregando.

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[![cuando agrego un botón u otro no se muestra ][2*

Comment: ¿Aumentaste el zoom?  ¿No tendrán el mismo color que el fondo y por eso no se ven?

Comment: amm ok deja y le ponga un color!!!

Comment: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE6IB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE6IB.png) ........................................

Comment: disculpe cual zoom debo aumentar?

Comment: aunque le he puesto color a los componentes no se me los visualiza

Comment: Arriba, a la derecha, tienes el zoom al `50%`, el valor que está entre los signos de `+` y de `-` ... Presionando sobre el signo de `+`  vas aumentando el zoom. Creo que sería bueno que leas un poco sobre cómo funciona Android Studio antes de lanzarte a programar con él,

Comment: Se han realizado varias preguntas similares en estas dos últimas semanas. Deberías buscar en el sitio para ver si alguna de las respuestas te sirve. Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones, y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio.